# How to determine the delta between values at similar but not equal coordinates?

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices of unequal length. Each matrix contains coordinates in one column and values associated to those coordinates in the second column.
The range of coordinates is similar in both cases, however, the coordinates are not exactly the same.
I want to find the delta between the values of the first and the second matrix. How do I overcome the issue of different coordinates?

Comment: In StackOverflow people usually only help if your question is specific enough and has a code of your specific problem. Please read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq and then provide the exact code that is causing the problem.

Comment: I guess my question is generic and broad.(Say like an existing function, concept). In this case, interpolation was what I was looking for(Newbie in matlab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try interpolating the values from one matrix to the coordinates of the other and plot the delta:

```
y = rand(25,1);
z = rand(30,1);

x{:,1} = linspace(0,1,size(y,1))'; 
x{:,2} = linspace(0,1,size(z,1))';

hold on
plot(x{:,1},y,'b');
plot(x{:,2},z,'r');

z_new = interp1(x{:,2},z,x{:,1});

zy_delta = y - z_new;

plot(x{:,1},zy_delta,'xk');
```

Both `y` and `z` are plotted against the same "non-dimensional" range, `[0,1]`. `z` has more points than `y` and the `rand` function provides a simple way of obtaining two different data-sets.
In the plot, one would be able to compare `y` and `z`. To measure the difference, use [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) - or any other interpolation you find suitable for your problem - to find the values of the dataset with the higher resolution at the coordinates of the data-set with the lower resolution.
Now you have two data-sets of equal length: `y` and `z_new`. Between those two, you can calculate the delta and plot it, if necessary.
In this case, `y` and `z` are different enough to yield substantial deltas. If they were closer, the deltas would be smaller.

Comment: Thanks a lot! (-Newbie in matlab.)

Comment: @Sreesh.V : you're welcome. just be careful when you interpolate, sometimes you might get *funky* results depending on how you do it.

Comment: Also, can we do the reverse? As in populate y with 5 more elements(make up the gaps by some method-linear,cubic,etc)?

Comment: @Sreesh.V : Try this: `y_new = interp1(x{;,1},y,x{:,2});`

Comment: Ah. I made a dumb mistake earlier. Thanks, again! Its exactly what I needed!(Ill check up the algorithm later).